# Glassfish DNS Configuration

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, glassfish

First of all, I know that I'm asking a basic question.

I'm a software developer and I'm not an expert in server administration and network stuff.

I have a VPS (Win 2008) with one static IP e.g. `10.20.30.40`.

I have also registered a domain name e.g. `mydomain.com`

I have installed Glassfish 3.1 open source edition on my machine. Now the application is accessable on `http://10.20.30.40` from outside and inside the server.

**My first question:**
In order to set the domain name for my application can I config the **Glassfish** without any DNS server or I need to add **DNS** Role on my **Windows 2008**?

---

**Explanation of second question:**
Since I didn;t know the answer of my first question I installed DNS on my Windows 2008 and defined `n1.mydomain.com` and `ns2.mydomain.com` and in my domain control panel I added these 2 addresses with IP`10.20.30.40`.

Now the application is accessible by IP and Domain inside the server but only by IP from outside.

**How can I config my whole server in a correct way?**

Comment: As a software developer, you're in the right place. However, as a sysadmin, this question is off topic. I suggest asking on serverfault.

Comment: If you create a new one, yes, you should probably delete this one.  If you wait a while, a moderator will probably migrate this one for you.

Comment: So I prefer the second way, at least by that time some developers can review my question, and I can understand their language better than server admins. :)

Comment: Is 10.20.30.40 your actual IP or are you just using the 10-net as an example for this question? The 10-net is a private IP network configuration and not routable across the Internet, if that is the actual IP you are working with.

Comment: it is my static (real) IP.

Comment: The 10-net address space is not Internet routable, so any DNS setup for this configuration will be non-Internet accessible unless there is a routable Internet IP involved somewhere/somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the actual IP is not a 10-net based one...

Normally one would only need to configure the DNS server managing your actual domain - typically at the "registrar" for a lot of folks these days. This would be accomplished with an "A Record" that would associate the desired DNS name with the Internet IP.

No need to setup additional DNS servers in most cases.

Comment: I need to install my own DNS server on my VPS.

Comment: With the 10-net configuration, you may be able to get by with host files versus having a DNS server setup.